# How to uninstall Mercurial on Windows 7?

Tags: mercurial

I installed Mercurial on Windows 7.

However, I find nothing to uninstall it.

Even in add/remove program for control panel, there is nothing

So where do I uninstall it?

Here is a link to the install I had:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/windows/mercurial-4.0.2-x64.msi

Comment: [@Cher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892263/cher), could you add some more information about the installer you used and where you got it from? I might be able to help, but I'd like to make sure I understand *exactly* what you did.

Comment: added a link to it!! thanks